# Proving that the set of non-universal CFGs is not in NP

Tags: complexity-theory, context-free, np

How do I prove that $\overline{\mathrm{ALL_{CFG}}}$ does not fall in NP, where

$\qquad\mathrm{ALL_{CFG}} = \{\langle G \rangle \mid G \text{ is a CFG}, L(G) = \Sigma^* \}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that universality of context-free grammars (that is, deciding whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$) is undecidable.

Comment: I thought it has something to do with proving $ALL_{CFG}$   is undecidable. But I don't know how to get from there to proving that it is not an NP problem.

Comment: Well, keep trying.

Comment: I'm not sure but this is what I come up with so far: $ALL_{CFG}$ is undecidable so $\overline{ALL_{CFG}}$ is undecidable too. undecidable languages can't be NP. is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Make sure that you understand why undecidable languages are not in NP.